# accessing Google API in Flex - get security error after deploying.

Tags: apache-flex, geocoding

I am using the Google Geocoding API (JSON URL) to perform some geocoding work. I can get it work in the development box. However, once I deploy the application to IIS, I got a security error and tell me the URL is not be able to reach.

Here is the message. 
security error accessing ULR - channel security error.

Here is the source code I use. I am pretty sure the URL is correct since I can get the result by accessing it directly in IE.

```
        //call google url serive
        var httpService : HTTPService = new HTTPService( );
        var temps:String = itemg["ADDRESS_1"] + "," + itemg["CITY"] + "," + itemg["STATE"];
        temps = CSVUtil.str_replace(temps,",",",+"); 
        temps = CSVUtil.str_replace(temps, " ","+"); 
        //var urlstring = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + temps + "&sensor=false";
        var urlstring:String = googleurl + temps + "&sensor=false";
        Alert.show(urlstring); 
        httpService.url = urlstring; 
        httpService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultFunction);
        httpService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, faultfunction);
        httpService.send();
        Alert.show("request send out");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the ***crossdomain.xml*** on your web server root folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```